# print the dynamic function names in LLVM

Tags: llvm

Given a program like this:

```
int gcd(para) {...}
int main() {
   ...
   int a = gcd(para1);
   int b = gcd(para2); 
   return 1; 
}
```

I want to instrument the code and print the function names that will be executed in order: i.e., main(), gcd(), gcd().

The problem is I don't know how to pass the function name as argument to helper function.

I wrote following: 
For helper function: 
   I use: `void printDynamicFuncName(char* FName) {}`

For pass: 
   I use:

```
Type* Int8 = Type::getInt8PtrTy(context);
Function *CalleeF = cast<Function>(F.getParent()->getOrInsertFunction("_Z20printDynamicFuncNamePc", Void, Int8, NULL));
Constant* arg = ConstantDataArray::getString(context, F.getName());
Builder.CreateCall(CalleeF, arg);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it myself!

I could use:

```
Type* Int8 = Type::getInt8PtrTy(context);
static IRBuilder<> Builder(context);
Instruction *I = &*inst_begin(F);
Function *CalleeF = cast<Function>(F.getParent() ->getOrInsertFunction("_Z20printDynamicFuncNamePc", Void, Int8, NULL));
 Builder.SetInsertPoint(I);
 Builder.CreateCall(CalleeF, Builder.CreateGlobalStringPtr(F.getName()), "");
```

While in the helper function:

```
 void printDynamicFuncName(char* FName) {
        errs() << "Function Name is " << FName << "\n";
    }
```